# calling a .net web service from java using net beans

Tags: java, .net, web-services

Hi i need to call a .net web service(.asmx) from java which is already available.. I only know the method prototype and WSDL.. i'm using netbeans IDE..
The signature of my method is..

```
public bool createPersonality(string containerPath, attr[] attributes, string clientTransID, string targetSite, out string serverTransID, out string resultCode, out string resultMsg)
```

Pls help me in calling this method.. this web service exposes its methods through SOAP and DSML services.

```
i have doubt in web service client wizard 
i) which client type to choose?
 jax-ws,jax-rpc

ii) how to pass tat 2nd parameter attr[] attributes...
please help me with the code.. let me know if there are any other dependencies...
```